# Is there any way to detect image is Blurry after capturing from Camera in Android (Except OpenCV )

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working with Camera2 API and want to detect captured image is blurry or clear, i used OpenCV for this but result is not satisfactory and it increases APK size 3 times, So is there any way to detect blurry?

Answer (score 4):

Measuring image focus/blur involves iterating of the pixels of the bitmap, or at least a portion thereof.

While you don't need OpenCV to iterate over the pixels of a bitmap on Android, its not for the faint of heart.  Doing so in a performant way would require you to drop into JNI native code, or perhaps a technology like RenderScript, as iterating over pixels in Java or Kotlin might prove too slow.

There are many algorithms and techniques for measuring focus, or sharpness, or contrast, this is one I've used with reasonable success.

Luma is the luminosity of a pixel, i.e. grayscale pixel value.  You'll want to convert each pixel to a grayscale value for this focus measure.  e.g. using the NTSC formula:

```
pixelLuma = (red * 0.299) + (green * 0.587) + (blue * 0.114)
```

> Here is a suggested formula to measure focus score:

```
FocusScore =  Max({Video_Gradient}) / {Gray_Level_Dynamic_Range} * {Pixel_Pitch}
```

**Max{Video_Gradient}** = a measure of the *maximum* luminosity difference between adjacent pixels (x,y) across the bitmap.

e.g.:

horizontally measure `pixel[x] - pixel[x+1]`

vertically measure `pixel[y] - pixel[y+1]`

**{Gray_Level_Dynamic_Range}** = difference between average of N lightest pixels and N darkest pixels across the bitmap.  A typical value for N is 64, in my case working on images around 1200w x 500h.  Smaller images should use smaller N.

**{Pixel_Pitch}** = 1 / DPI = 1/200 = 0.005

This will result in a score, higher values are more in focus.  You can determine a reasonable threshold.

Here is a code snippet written in C:

> - width = width of bitmap
> - height = height of bitmap
> - pixels = an array of bytes of size (width * height) holding pixel luminosity values
> - VFOCUS_N = 64

```
int gradientHorizontal[256];
int *pGradientHorizontal = gradientHorizontal;
int gradientVertical[256];
int *pGradientVertical = gradientVertical;
int luminanceHistogram[256];
int *pLuminance = luminanceHistogram;
int maxGradient = 0;

for (int i = 0;i < 256;i++)
{
    gradientHorizontal[i] = 0;
    gradientVertical[i] = 0;
    luminanceHistogram[i] = 0;
}

// pixel by pixel math...
for (nRow = 0; nRow < height-1; nRow++)
{
    nRowOffset = nRow * width;
    nNextRowOffset = (nRow+1) * width;

    for (nCol = 0; nCol < width-1; nCol++)
    {
        int gC = pixels[nRowOffset + nCol];
        int gH = abs(gC - pixels[nRowOffset + nCol + 1]);
        int gV = abs(gC - pixels[nNextRowOffset + nCol]);
        pLuminance[gC]++;
        pGradientHorizontal[gH]++;
        pGradientVertical[gV]++;
    }
}

// find max gradient
for (int i = 255;i >= 0;i--)
{
    // first one with a value
    if ((gradientHorizontal[i] > 0) || (gradientVertical[i] > 0))
    {
        maxGradient = i;
        break;
    }
}

// calculate dynamic range
int rangeLow = 0;
int rangeHi = 0;
int p;
p = 0;
for (int i = 0;i < 256;i++)
{
    if (luminanceHistogram[i] > 0)
    {
        if (p + luminanceHistogram[i] > VFOCUS_N)
        {
            rangeLow += (i * (VFOCUS_N - p));
            p = VFOCUS_N;
            break;
        }

        p += luminanceHistogram[i];
        rangeLow += (i * luminanceHistogram[i]);
    }
}
if (p)
    rangeLow /= p;

p = 0;
for (int i = 255;i >= 0;i--)
{
    if (luminanceHistogram[i] > 0)
    {
        if (p + luminanceHistogram[i] > VFOCUS_N)
        {
            rangeHi += (i * (VFOCUS_N - p));
            p = VFOCUS_N;
            break;
        }

        p += luminanceHistogram[i];
        rangeHi += (i * luminanceHistogram[i]);
    }
}
if (p)
    rangeHi /= p;

float mFocusScore = (float)fmin((float)maxGradient / (fabs((float)rangeHi - (float)rangeLow) * 0.005), 100.00);
```

Low focus scores means a blurry image.  Values close to or in excess of 100 indicate a sharp image, the code above caps the score at 100.

Comment: Could you provide complete blurry detection method?

Comment: Answer posted is not complete.

Comment: This is a nice simple approach indeed, I am wondering if and how you did find it and if you evaluated it against other rather complex methods like laplacian variance and/or other high level approaches?

Comment: @Thomas indeed this isn't my own formula/technique but one I found documented in a Standard document related to check image processing (i.e. financial documents).  Because our implementation runs on mobile devices we needed something highly performant so there was no evaluation of other methods.  The above has been very reliable for us