# Detect blur image using MLKit (TensorFlow)

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-camera2, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I am working on camera2 api and sometime getting blur images while capturing images from camera. I need to check if clicked image is blur or not, Using openCV increase the .apk size 3x times. I also check the solution posted on a SO thread [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565533/is-there-any-way-to-detect-image-is-blurry-after-capturing-from-camera-in-androi) but seems incomplete.

Is it possible to detect if image is blur or not using MLKit? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.